# Proof of Limits

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n}} = 0$$

Using the formal definition of convergence.

Workings:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{n}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n}}$

To make $\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{n}}$ less than $\epsilon$.

Need $\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{n}}$ < $\epsilon$

That is $\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{\epsilon}} < n$

So let $N = \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{n}}$

Proof:

Suppose $\epsilon > 0$

Let $N = \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{n}}$

For any $n > N$ we have that $n > \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{\epsilon}}$.

And we have:

$|s_n - L| = \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n}} - 0\right|$

$|s_n - L| = \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n}}\right|$

$|s_n - L| = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n}}$

$\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{n}}$

$< \frac{1}{N}$

$\leq \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$

$= \epsilon$

Therefore:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n}} = 0$$

I'm not sure if I did this correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't that $\geq$? $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{3}} \geq \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Supposed to say $\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to take $N = 1/\sqrt[5]{n}$, because it depends on the index of the sequence and not on $\epsilon$. Instead, let $N$ be an integer greater than $1/\epsilon^4$. Then for $n \ge N$,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{N}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1/\epsilon^4}} = \frac{1}{1/\epsilon} = \epsilon.$$

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Thanks for the help.